# how to create a border around constraint layout along with an option for title

Tags: android, android-styles

I need to achieve the style like below

[image]

but, I have a constraint layout inside which so many sub layouts I have, which resembles a edit text view with feature like editing particular set of values by locking editing of other values.

Now I know how to give border around constraint layout using below code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#6B000000" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

But, I'm not getting how to set title like in above image.

I tried to put textview with negative margin/padding like below, But it didn't work

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textColor="@color/logoDark"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_style"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingTop="-20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All above answers are focusing on creating new layouts. But you don't suppose to do that. Just create a TextView below your constraint layout.

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/time_range"
        android:textColor="@color/logoDark"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_style"

        // Below are very important to achieve title on border 
        android:paddingStart="2dp" 
        android:paddingEnd="2dp" 
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" 
        android:background="@color/cnstrbkg" 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cnstLyt" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cnstLyt" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cnstLyt" />
```

The positioning of textview is very very important thing. Change it to move text view at any position you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's sounds like your TextView is inside the ConstraintLayout you want to frame, it should be outside. So that you overlay the ConstraintLayout. Somehow like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/white">

       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          android:id="@+id/framed_layout"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:background="@drawable/outside_shape"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

          ....
          ....
          ....

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

       <TextView
         android:layout_width="30dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:text="title"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/framed_layout"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/framed_layout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

or you wrap it with a CoordinatorLayout, looks the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/white">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/framed_layout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/outside_shape">

    ....
    ....
    ....
    
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="title" />

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

outside_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle" >
     <corners
       android:radius="10dp"
     />
     <solid
       android:color="@android:color/white"
     />
     <stroke
       android:width="1dp"
       android:color="@android:color/black"
     />
     </shape>
```

with outside_shape it looks like this

[image]

Comment: This is affecting my other views. I don't know why.

Comment: but it looks the way you want it? I added a nother way to wrap it.

Comment: Yes, My constraint layout is dynamically creating some views inside it. So, their is a problem